# how do you get your current screen in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

so i have my main app class which looks like this

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def on_resize(self):
        if self.app.manager.get_screen() == "table_screen":   
            if self.width>self.height:
                self.manager.get_screen("table_screen").ids.table_image.source="table1.png"
                self.manager.get_screen("table_screen").ids.left_panel.opacity=0
            else:
                self.ids.left_panel.size_hint_x=.5
                self.ids.left_panel.opacity=1
    def build(self):
        Window.bind(size=self.on_resize())
        return Main()
```

and i want to firstly know that the current screen is "table_screen" and later i need to get ids from that screen, but with current code i get an error

```
 if self.root.manager.get_screen() == "table_screen":
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'manager
```

so  what is the way to do it?
here is my Main

```
class Main(MDBoxLayout):
    pass
```

and here is my Main in kv

```
<Main>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    id: main
    ScreenManager:
        id:SM
```

Comment: What is your `Main` class? Is it a `ScreenManager`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Also, note that `Window.bind(size=self.on_resize())` is incorrect. It should be `Window.bind(size=self.on_resize)` without the extra `()`.

Comment: added my main class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change

```
Window.bind(size=self.on_resize())
```

to

```
Window.bind(size=self.on_resize)
```

Since the root class for your `App` contains the `ScreenManager`, you can rewrite your `on_resize()` as:

```
def on_resize(self, *args):
    if self.root.ids.SM.current == "table_screen":   
        if self.width>self.height:
            self.root.ids.SM.current_screen.ids.table_image.source="table1.png"
            self.root.ids.SM.current_screen.ids.left_panel.opacity=0
        else:
            self.ids.left_panel.size_hint_x=.5
            self.ids.left_panel.opacity=1
```

The `current` property of the `ScreenManager` contains the name of the current screen and the `current_screen` property contains a reference to the current `Screen` object. Since you have not posted a MCVE, I cannot be sure that your use of `ids` is correct.

Comment: that indeed fixed the first problem, but now i get an  TypeError: on_resize() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given error, what can be the origin of this error?

Comment: Note my edited answer with `def on_resize(self, *args):`.